# Не работает ответ от запроса, отправленного Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json, angularjs

Добрый день! Делаю первые шаги в Angular 2, сильно не критикуйте за  вопрос новичка. Отправляю из компонента запрос к базе данных на чтение таблицы. Код такой

```
var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
httpRequest.open('GET', 'http://test1.ru/loadbooks.php', true);
httpRequest.send();
httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (httpRequest.readyState == 4 && httpRequest.status == 200) {
    var httpResult = JSON.parse(httpRequest.responseText);
    gridOptions.api.setRowData(httpResult);
  }
}
```

Сразу скажу, что приложение разрабатываю локально с использованием Denwer, php-скрипты вынес за пределы Angular-приложения (правильно ли это?). Код самого скрипта, дающего ответ.

```
<?php
    $link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "")  or die('Не удалось соединиться: ' . mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("united") or die('Не удалось выбрать базу данных');
    $query = "SELECT * FROM books";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die('Запрос не удался: ' . mysql_error());
    $data = array(); 
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){ 
        $data[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($data);

    mysql_free_result($result);
    mysql_close($link);

?>
```

Вроде все просто, но эта связка не работает, не приходит ответ от сервера. Что я делаю не так? Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Что в консоле? что сервер ответил на запрос в разделе Network?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здравствуй, Andrew!
Думаю, проблема в том, что вы присваиваете onreadystatechange функцию обработки ответа после того как запрос был совершен. А так как все запросы идут на localhost, вполне вероятно, что ответ приходит до того, как данная функция инициализируется.
Попробуйте добавить `httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {...}` перед `httpRequest.open('GET', 'http://test1.ru/loadbooks.php', true);`
Надеюсь, мой ответ вам поможет.